# Does Disque have a feature like RedisJobStore in redis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, apscheduler, disque

I wanted to use disque as a job-store.
I implemented the same with redis using **RedisJobStore** Class in Apscheduler.

Here is the snippet with redis job-store:

```
    from apscheduler.jobstores.redis import RedisJobStore
    job_stores = {
                  'default': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='ap_scheduler.jobs', run_times_key='ap_scheduler.run_times')
    }
```

Is it possible to create a wrapper using RedisJobStore class to create job store in disque which can then be use by apscheduler?

```
  class RedisJobStore(BaseJobStore):
      def __init__(self, db=0, jobs_key='apscheduler.jobs', run_times_key='apscheduler.run_times',
             pickle_protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL, **connect_args):
    super(RedisJobStore, self).__init__()
    c = Client(['localhost:7711'])
    self.disque = c.connect()

    def lookup_job(self, job_id):
        job_state = self.disque.hget(self.jobs_key, job_id)
        return self._reconstitute_job(job_state) if job_state else 
               None
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its been figured out by me